# write in file and STDOUT from perl script

Tags: perl, stdout

Hi I need to have perl script's output in both file and `STDOUT` but I cannot redirect output from shel like `./a.pl > out.log`. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need it going to stdout? Is someone going to watch that, or is it being redirected as well?

Comment: @sputnick, the simple answer to this question is [man tee](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tee).  Gayane made use of the unix command line and didn't reference any other OSes.  Your link doesn't even mention tee.

Comment: @JulianFondren I don't agree, OP seems to said that he don't have control of command line

Comment: @sputnick, just now, yes :-/  But scripts (`#!/bin/sh` , `realscript | tee log`) are a away to "force users" and Gayane already has them invoking a script, so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you should be using

```
./a.pl | tee out.log
```

but it sounds like you will reject that. Next best is probably [File::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTee).

```
use File::Tee qw( tee );
tee(STDOUT, '>', 'out.log');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

`a.pl | tee out.log`

Comment: actually The script is being run by other people, I cannot force the to call it  in other way. So I need to do something in script (redirect/save STDOUT or something else)

Comment: @Gayane, So you're saying you know better than your users what they want. You should never force your users to do anything.

Comment: They want to have the output both in log and in STDOUT. But they don't want to redirect output from shell

Comment: Use the File::Tee module ikegami mentioned but be careful about the file you redirect your STDOUT to (always append or maybe create a unique file every time the script is run or a new file per day)